# system.linq to sum rows with same ID in gridview

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have an issue with the same problem again but this time its with summing rows of the same ID in a gridview. I have two columns in my gridview named ID and quantity. the agenda is that i have to type in the ID and quantity manually, and i am trying to sum up quantity  with the same row ID. An example would be

ID     Quantity
1234   1

1234   1

8976   2

8976   2

so when i press a button , ID 1234 would have 2 quantity and 8976 would have 4 quantity.
I tired using the group by function in system.linq but my columns and rows turn out to have an empty cell. Does anyone have a solution to solving it? Any helpw ould be greatly appreciated.

Below are my codes snippet

my main form class

```
int id = 0;
        int qty = 0;

        List<QuantityPerID> qtyList = new List<QuantityPerID>();



        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            if (null != row.Cells[0].Value)
            {
                id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            }
            if (null != row.Cells[1].Value)
            {
                qty = int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }
            var sales = qtyList.Select(s => s.ID).Distinct().Select(order => new QuantityPerID
            {
                ID = order,
                Quantity= qtyList.Where(s => s.ID == order).Sum(s => s.Quantity),

            }).ToList();
            var source = new BindingSource();
            source.DataSource = qtyList;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sales;
```

My quantityperID class codes

```
class QuantityPerID
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is the result coming of current query

Comment: only the header ID and quantity is displaying while the rest of the numbers became empty cells

Comment: what are other headers, obviosuly the will not be displayed because you are only passing ID and quantity to gridview source

Comment: i only got two headers which are ID and quantity.. but have you got any idea how do i pass the number into the gridview source?